# How are subcommands used in Tcl/Tk?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, subcommand

Reading [this entry](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm#M15) in the Tcl/Tk online reference i came across this paragraph where it states:

> The combobox widget also supports the following ttk::entry widget
>   subcommands (see ttk::entry(n) for details):
>
> - bbox
> - delete
> - icursor
> - index
> - insert
> - selection
> - xview

I know in this case of the Combobox widget it's comprised partially of an Entry widget but how exactly are subcommands used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the common Tk command structure, and you'll need it to interact with any Tk widget.  A subcommand of a widget is done by using the pathname of the object as the base command, then the subcommand you want.  E.g.,

```
ttk::combobox .cb
.cb insert 0 "my text"
```

Comment: ah right, thanks. So a subcommand is a command that can be used with a widget which is passed to a sub-widget. I just tested it and it works great!

Comment: No, in general it's more like a keyword that a widget command recognizes and acts upon. There is (usually) no sub-widget involved, though in the case of a combobox one could probably see it as the combobox _delegating_ the subcommand to its entry component. But that's more the exception than the rule.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is, like this: *pathname* *subcommand* ?*arg*...?, i.e. you begin the invocation with the pathname to the widget (which is the name of a command which was generated when you created the widget), then the subcommand, then any arguments.

I'm not sure if that's what you're asking about, however. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Subcommands are very much like methods of an object system; with those examples in Tk, you give the name of the object (the widget) as one argument, the name of the method (the subcommand) as the next argument, and any further arguments that are required after that.

If you follow the link on that manual page, it will take you to the exact description of how to use them. For example, it says that the **index** subcommand is exactly as is supported by the **ttk::entry** widget, and going to [that page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_entry.htm) you see:

> *pathName* **index** *index*
>             Returns the numerical index corresponding to *index*.

The definition of *index* is further up the page (and could be better cross-referenced, I accept).

> ### INDICES
>
> Many of the **entry** widget commands take one or more indices as arguments. An index specifies a particular character in the entry's string, in any of the following ways:
>
> > *number*
> >     Specifies the character as a numerical index, where 0 corresponds to the first character in the string.
> >
> > **@***number*
> >     In this form, *number* is treated as an x-coordinate in the entry's window; the character spanning that x-coordinate is used. For example, “**@0**” indicates the left-most character in the window.
> >
> > **end**
> >     Indicates the character just after the last one in the entry's string. This is equivalent to specifying a numerical index equal to the length of the entry's string.
> >
> > **insert**
> >     Indicates the character adjacent to and immediately following the insert cursor.
> >
> > **sel.first**
> >     Indicates the first character in the selection. It is an error to use this form if the selection is not in the entry window.
> >
> > **sel.last**
> >     Indicates the character just after the last one in the selection. It is an error to use this form if the selection is not in the entry window.
>
> Abbreviations may be used for any of the forms above, e.g.  “**e**” or “**sel.l**”. In general, out-of-range indices are automatically rounded to the nearest legal value.

Generally speaking, the insight of subcommands corresponding to methods applies relatively easily (and is directly used in the main object systems for Tcl) though it gets a little bit tricky with sub-subcommands. In effect, the method delegates to an inner object for dispatch.

Comment: Getting that manual excerpt to look reasonable in Markdown was unreasonably hard!